# Occasional and Momentary Site-to-Site VPN Tunnel Failures

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, ipsec, sophos

I just started managing a number of locations that have site-to-site VPN connections. Part of what I've been doing is going through the Sophos firewalls examining alerts, findings and incidents. While doing this I've noticed that there are a number of alerts for VPN tunnels going down for as little as 30secs and as long as a few minutes. The issues will happen at the location from as much as a few times a week to once a week. I've dug through the logs and from what I'm able to gather the issue appears to be an excessive amount of failed ICMP pings. By excessive I mean from a half dozen to a dozen and a half, if not more, within a one or two minute period. Internal/external network connections don't appear to have any issues and there haven't been any alerts for gateways/modems going down or experiencing service issues. I've kind of just chalked it up to momentary blips. Though I wanted to post here to see if anyone could impart any wisdom upon me or give me some insight into what might be happening. Thanks in advance!